# Нужно ли ставить двоеточие в данном предложении? Если да, то какое правило на это указывает?

Tags: двоеточие

Помощь: фронту, участникам СВО и их семьям.

Comment: Обосновать нельзя ни двоеточие, ни то, что предложение.

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие ставится перед перечислением:

1. Если перечислению предшествует обобщающее слово, например:

> Отовсюду поднялись казаки: от Чигирина, от Переяслава, от Батурина, от Глухова, от низовой стороны днепровской и от всех его вepховий и островов.
>
> Гоголь

2. **Если перед перечислением нет обобщающего слова, но необходимо предупредить читателя, что далее следует какой-либо перечень**, например:

> Из-под сена виднелись: самовар, кадка с мороженной формой и еще кой-какие привлекательные узелки и коробочки.
>
> Л. Толстой

В вашем случае - перечень.